# bash awk - need associative array output from a php script

Tags: php, arrays, linux, bash, awk

I have a php script that is responsible for returning names and associated id's from a database:

```
//general array structure is:
$array = array(
    "name1" => 001,
    "name2" => 002,
    ...
);
return $array;
```

I also have some awk code that needs to have access to this array, and turn it into a map. The php script can be modified to accommodate this. This is the awk script:

```
//awk:
system("/usr/bin/php /path/to/script/query_db.php")

//query_db.php:
echo implode(' ', $results);
```

What I don't know how to do is make an array in awk, given the above. This only echoes the values returned from the php script's array, and elides the keys.

Comment: In what format does the awk script need this?

Comment: As stated above, the awk script needs to access the associative array as a map. @dipenshah - If you want I can post everything I have tried, but how is that helpful?

Comment: We require a working example to see how far you are. Consider reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: There is no "map" type in PHP, so it would have to be another format, probably string that awk then transforms into a "map".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple. From PHP use this loop to dump the array:

```
<?php
foreach ($array as $k=>$v) echo "$k=$v\n";
?>
```

**output:**

```
name1=1
name2=2
```

Now in awk use `=` as field separator and populate the associative array:

```
php -s arr.php | awk -F= '{arr[$1]=$2} END{for (i in arr) print i, a[i]}'
```